# Distance calculation without knowing time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, distance

I’m studying physics and am struggling to work out the correct formula for the below example question. Any help and explanation would be amazing.

A tourist being chased by a bear is running in a straight line towards his car at a speed of 4.0m/s. the car is a distance “d” away. The bear is 26m behind him and running at a speed of 6.0m/s. the tourist reaches the car safely. What is the maximum possible value for d?

What would be the formula used to work the above question out? Without knowing the time it took him to travel the unknown distance?

Any help and explanation to the above problem would be amazing.

This is not a homework question it is a learning and understanding question from a textbook. The answer is give by the textbook, but it does not show how it reached the answer or the formula used to work it out.

I would like to know what the formula used could be so that I can better understand how to answer this type of question in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the relative velocity is 2.0m/s. You know the bear was 26m behind the tourist. From this you can find the time the bear will take to catch up with the tourist. This is also the maximum time the tourist has to arrive at his getaway vehicle. Knowing his speed, you can then solve for the maximum distance he was alway from his vehicle.

Comment: Thanks iaexo, I tried this and I came to 17.2M but that is not the answer the answer is 52m according to the textbook. However the text book does not show workings or how it go to this answer. That is what I need to know and understand. So having the above information and the final answer how would you work this out. What is the calculation you would use. I know normally it would be D=V/T but that does not work in this case at least I have not been able to get it to work.

Comment: @GarryMoroney (26 m) / (2 m/s) = 13 s. How far do the tourist & the bear run in 13 seconds?